# how to fetch data from 2 tables in SQL with null Entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join, union

My Tables and look like this

```
-- t1
id  col_1
1   Tim
2   Marta

-- t2
id  col_2
1   Tim
3   Katarina
```

I want my results like this?

```
--Result
id   col_1       col_2
1    Tim           Tim
2    Marta        *Null*
3   *Null*      Katarina
```

if someone knows how can I do this using SQL then please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a FULL OUTER JOIN, so you need to simulate it, but be warned that is slw

> ```
> CREATE tABLE t1(id int, col_1 varchar(50))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,'Tim'),(2,'Martqa')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE t2(id int, col_2 varchar(50))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1,'Tim'),(3,'Katarina')
> ```

> ```
> SeLECT t1.id, t1.col_1,t2.col_2
> FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 USING(id)
> UNION 
> SeLECT t2.id, t1.col_1,t2.col_2
> FROM t1 RIGHT JOIN t2 USING(id)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | col_1  | col_2   
> -: | :----- | :-------
>  1 | Tim    | Tim     
>  2 | Martqa | null    
>  3 | null   | Katarina
> ```

> ```
> SeLECT t1.id, t1.col_1,t2.col_2
> FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 USING(id)
> WHERE t1.id > 1
> UNION 
> SeLECT t2.id, t1.col_1,t2.col_2
> FROM t1 RIGHT JOIN t2 USING(id)
> WHERE t2.id > 1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | col_1  | col_2   
> -: | :----- | :-------
>  2 | Martqa | null    
>  3 | null   | Katarina
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM
> (SeLECT t1.id, t1.col_1,t2.col_2
> FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
> UNION 
> SeLECT t2.id, t1.col_1,t2.col_2
> FROM t1 RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id) t1
> WHERE id > 1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | col_1  | col_2   
> -: | :----- | :-------
>  2 | Martqa | null    
>  3 | null   | Katarina
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c700b1469c97ff6919103a4b601c4855)*

Comment: @rehmanali see changed answer,, you can play around in the fiddle to see what results you get when you change the where clauses

Answer (score 0):

You want a `full join`, which MySQL does not support  One way is to get all the ids and use `left join`:

```
select *
from (select id from t1
      union    -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select id from t2
     ) i left join
     t1
     using (id) left join
     t2
     using (id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.id, t1.col_1, t2.col_2
FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON (t1.id=t2.id)
UNION
SELECT t2.id, t1.col_1, t2.col_2
FROM t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 ON (t2.id = t1.id)
```